# Use a single html as a 'details' page for multiple elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

This is my question, I have an `index.html` that has a table populated with a jQuery ajax function. I want to know how do I link each table element to a single page called `details.html` that should be populated using some parameter from index.html (e.g. `details.html?id=2` has different data than `details.html?id=9` but they both have the same structure)

Assuming that I can only use html and jquery, how would I do that?

I mean, how (in details.html) can I get the `id=2` or `id=9` parameter?

Thanks in advance (I'm sorry if this question is kind of noobish, but I'm not so used to html)

Comment: Why `html` & why not php?

Comment: @PleaseWait What makes you think the OP is using PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get url parameter jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)

Comment: for a homework using apache cordova (phonegap) ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to do it like that use something like this:

```
var url = document.URL;
var tmpURL = url.split("?id=").pop();
```

In tmpURL is the value of id parameter (from your example 2 or 9).  Hope it helps.